# Switching depending on resistance from fuel gauge sender unit

Tags: resistance, switching

I hope someone can offer a solution to the following situation:

We currently have a fuel gauge operating at between 12,6 and 14,6 VDC. The sender unit ranges from 10 ohms (empty) to 300 ohms (full).

My question is whether it is possible to use the resistance values mentioned to control a fuel transfer pump relay, preferably to switch on at 100 ohms and switch off at 250 ohms?

Your advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This could be done with eg a quad package of opamps (LM324) and a few resistors and diodes. Component cost $5-$10. Maybe less. || OR if acceptable you could use an eg Arduino microcontroller, a resistor or few, a low cost transistor to drive the relay and maybe a voltage regulator*. You use a resistor or two (or a trimpot) to scale the sensor output into the 0-5V range. The program then is basically. || If Vin > Vhigh then turn pump off. | If Vin < Vlow turn pump on. || You may wish to add some security features but that's basically "it". ...

Comment: ... You will have no trouble finding people to help with the Arduino programming - and not a lot more learning it yourself from scratch. It's MADE for people who start off knowing somewhat less than zilch about such things. All up cost - under $US5. || *Some Arduinos will technically run on 12V in but it is very wise to use a power supply regulator to drop Vin to near 5V. This helps keep out power transients etc. More detaails can be provided if this approach sounds useful.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that *"Is it possible ...?"* is a yes/no question. In this case, the answer is "Yes". If you're asking us to design it for you, that would be too broad. You would need to specify something about the level of performance you expect as well as what constraints you have on the implementation. What is your specific question?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a DC voltage monitoring relay.

[image]

*Figure 1. A random voltage monitoring relay.*

Something like that of Figure 1 has some nice features. Without reading the datasheet I would guess that it has adjustable on / off delay, hysteresis (the difference between the on and off switching points) and a U-W function - whatever that is!

If it's still on the original circuit you can simply monitor the output with a monitoring relay. If the sender is not in-circuit already then you'll have to feed a safe current through it to generate the varying voltage for the relay.

Take care that the device is explosion proof as required.